# Symfony2: addMethodCall doesn't work in Extension

Tags: symfony, service

I must be missing something. I have a "ConfigBundle" inside of which I have this services.yml (in Acme/ConfigBundle/Resources/config):

```
services:
    config.manager:
        class: Acme\ConfigBundle\Manager\ConfigManager
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager", "@config.storage"]
```

This service works as expected.

Next I have a Configuration.php:

```
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('config');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('storage')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                ->variableNode('defaults')->end()
            ->end();
        ;

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Which also works as expected. And at the end I have ConfigExtensions.php:

```
class ConfigExtension extends ConfigurableExtension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function loadInternal(array $mergedConfig, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        // Set storage service.
        $container->setAlias('config.storage', $mergedConfig['storage']);

        if (!empty($mergedConfig['defaults'])) {
            $loader = new YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
            $loader->load('services.yml');
            //$container->getDefinition('config.manager')->addArgument('test');
            $container->getDefinition('config.manager')->addMethodCall('setDefaults', [$mergedConfig['defaults']]);
            var_dump('It is being invoked!');

        }
    }

}
```

Which doesn't work as expected because method `addMethodCall` doesn't work. `addMethodCall` executes, I checked this, but the call is never invoked and is not visible in appDevDebugProjectContainer.xml in cache. When I add:

```
    calls:
        - [setDefaults, ['test']]
```

To my service definition in services.yml it gets invoked, but I cannot achieve it by using `addMethodCall` in Extension. I'm not getting any errors, I cleared cache directory, more than once, when trying to figure this out. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

Comment: The containerBuilder you are working on is a copy. You need to create a compiler pass and do your service related stuff there.

Comment: @Twifty post it as an answer so I could accept it :) .